# Xpath select element where both children contains text

Tags: javascript, xpath

How do I select an element where both of the children contains a specific text.

Example:

```
<div class="line">
     <h1>
          <a>1</a>
     </h1>
     <p>
          <a>2</a>
     </p>
</div>
<div class="line">
     <h1>
          <a>3</a>
     </h1>
     <p>
          <a>4</a>
     </p>
</div>
```

How do I make an XPath string that, search for the class line, and then select it where one of the spans contain 3 and 4

I tried this

```
//div[contains(@class, 'line')]
```

but I don't see how I can select it where first child contains `3` and second contains `4`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this one to select `div` node by exact string values of two child nodes

```
//div[contains(@class, 'line') and normalize-space(h1)='3' and normalize-space(p)='4']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But how would I do it if the 2 elements are inside other elements? Look at the update, Thanks!

Comment: @RookieNeedingHelp , `//div[contains(@class, 'line') and .//a='3' and .//a='4']`

Comment: Hmm, when I test this in selenium-webdriver, I get an error. It says its invalid

Comment: @RookieNeedingHelp Did you use single quotes for XPath or double quotes? Share exception log

Comment: This is what i wrote //div[contains(@class, 'line') and .//a[contains(lower-case(text(),'1')] and .//a[contains(lower-case(text(),'2')]]

Comment: @RookieNeedingHelp , OK... So 1) This is not my XPath :) 2) You forgot some closing parenthesis 3) You cannot use `lower-case` as this function is from XPath 2.0 while Selenium supports XPath 1.0 only